# highcharts. set full height of column/bar background color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to set a gradient background color to full height of column in Highcharts. Like on the image below. How can I do it? Help me, please.

[here an example of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z4XA.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make another series which has points equaled yAxis maximum value. You can use [pattern-fill](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill) plugin and set the pattern to a specific column.

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },

    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 100
    },

    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        pointPadding: 0
      }
    },

    series: [{
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        showInLegend: false,
        grouping: false,
        color: 'url(#highcharts-default-pattern-1)',
        data: [100, 100]
    }, {
      data: [20, 50]
    }, {
      data: [40, 30]
    }]
});
```

You can read more about modifying/creating patterns here - http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/rgs9uv39/

[image: column pattern background]

Answer (score -3):

Go here and import your image: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and after get your css properties.

If you need the element to be full height use:

```
.yourClass {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: the question is about setting background color but your answer is irrelevant